# Google Analytics API Accessing through Java

Tags: java, grails, google-analytics, vaadin

I am trying to write a java programm that connects to the Google Analytics API to send and retrieve data. I am totally new to this entire Google Analytics stuff, totally new to using API, but have good founded Java knowledge. Since I have spent all my time so far developping local application with barely any interaction to the outside world, I am kind of lost. I have spent hours on the web looking for good tutorials including the 'basics' of API handling, but was unsuccesful, yet. Does anyone have a good paper / tutorial for newbies he could recommend? The Software I am currently writing is, for now all local, but should be deployed at one point within the next 12 month on to a server (I am actually considering using GRails or Vaadin to make a Web-App out of the software ounce the core functionalities like the API-related stuff is done).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java